# Routing issue, server with LAN & WAN ports running Debian Jessie with FusionPBX

Tags: linux, networking, debian, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am trying to wrap up a FusionPBX install on Jessie. The network for this company is not what im used to.

The server has two Ethernet ports, one is LAN the other is WAN. I am running iptables, fail2ban(both setup by the Fusion PBX script, however I have been trying my own iptables chains from the working server this will replace). The sever I am replacing is setup the exact same far as networking and iptables.

On the new sever when I try to have my phones register to the new server they fail if my network config is like I have posted below. They will register when I change the default gate way to 192.168.0.1 on eth0. However when that happens I get one way audio, since the calls come in the wan(eth1) and try to exit via eth0(default gateway).

When I change the default gateway to be on the WAN and use interface eth1 the calls have 2 way audio, but the phones will not register via the LAN.

I am used to servers typically having either a wan or a lan but not both. Do I just need 2 default routes? Any insight would be a great big help.

**The primary network interface**

```
allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.45
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
####gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
dns-search mydomain.com
```

**WAN interface**

```
allow-hotplug eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static

address 172.217.3.174
netmask 255.255.255.252
network 172.217.3.172
broadcast 172.217.3.175  
gateway 172.217.3.173
```

Answer (score 0):

Each SIP profile in FreeSWITCH binds to one IP address and  port. You need to control that, and probably you need multiple profiles, as you have two NICs. I don't know how it's controlled in Fusionpbx, but there should be settings about that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is my first freeswitch project so I didnt realize thats how it did that. I did see that it created some directories based on my IP so that would make sense. Ill check that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to register to multiple interface on your server then you need to have multiple profile for multiple interface in freeswitch.